# jquery how to make a While that get all element start with String and get last 2 integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

Hello friends I have a problem, I would like to help to solve.
I have an indefinite amount of Element in the following format:

```
<input type="text" id="p_fase_1" name="p_fase_1" value="1" required>
<input type="text" id="p_fase_2" name="p_fase_2" value="1" required>
```

the difference in each element is the ID and the name and ending with different numbers.

I require to get the highest number of all element that start with this id String in the ID and the value it has.

```
p_fase_"this number" value="this value"
```

Code:

```
[id^="p_fase_"]
```

like taking a while with these element and save the greatest values in a variable

Comment: U=You want the greatest value of these elements? What do you mean here: `p_fase_"this number" value="this value"` ??? Do you want to extract name number too or what?

Comment: You should provide example of expected result regarding your provided HTML markup because imho this is unclear question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nuaoch70/

I made it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var highestNumber = 0;
    $("input[id^='p_fase_']").each(function() {
        var number = $(this).attr("id").replace("p_fase_", "");
        highestNumber = Math.max(highestNumber, number);
    });

    console.log("Highest Number is: " + highestNumber);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> I require to get the highest number of all element that start with
>   this id String in the ID and the value it has

So it would be:

```
var maxO = $('[id^="p_fase_"]').map(function(){
    return {idNum: this.id.split('_').pop(), value: this.value};
}).get().sort(function(a,b){
    return a.idNum - b.idNum;
}).pop();

console.log(maxO);
```

### -jsFiddle-

<strike>You co>uld map elements and get max value using:</strike>

```
var max = Math.max.apply(null, $('[id^="p_fase_"]').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}));
```

If you want the max number set in `name` attribute:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(null, $('[id^="p_fase_"]').map(function(){
    return this.name.split('_').pop();
}));
```

In `id`:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(null, $('[id^="p_fase_"]').map(function(){
    return this.id.split('_').pop();
}));
```

Comment: @mapodev Works as i expect it here: http://jsfiddle.net/qgkjy4rg/  But i'm really not sure that's the question...

Comment: ah ok, it's working for the value. I assumed it was ment to catch the number in the id, my fault

Comment: @mapodev i now think he wants the name number: here it would be: https://jsfiddle.net/c2z5b8o0/

Comment: @mapodev My bad, it is ID, i miis this part in question: `I require to get the highest number of all element that start with this id String in the ID and the value it has`